# Qt C++ class variable uninitialized

Tags: c++, qt, initialization

### Platform

> OS  -> ubuntu 15.10 x64
>   IDE -> qt creator 
>   cxx -> clang x64

uninitialized variable " a b c d e f g h ", but when runing " b e g " value are always zero; why ?

#### *Code*

```
enter code here
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    void show() {
        int e;
        int f;
        int g;
        int h;
        printf("value show a = 0x%08X , b = 0x%08X , c = 0x%08X , d = 0x%08X\n", a, b, c, d);
        printf("value show e = 0x%08X , f = 0x%08X , g = 0x%08X , h = 0x%08X\n", e, f, g, h);
        printf("mapid show e = 0x%08X , f = 0x%08X , g = 0x%08X , h = 0x%08X\n", &e, &f, &g, &h);
    }

private:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
};


int main()
{
    A aaa;
    aaa.show();
    int a;
    printf("0x%08x\n", a);

    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not? "Uninitialized" doesn't mean "something that's not zero". And using the value of uninitialized variables is undefined.

Comment: but in my running environment , the variable " b e g " is definited and always zero ; I run many times . you can try !

Comment: I suppose you're expecting to see something that you can identify as "random garbage", but "uninitialized" also doesn't mean "not the same on subsequent executions", and 0 is no less indeterminate than 2384373. C++ imposes no requirements whatsoever on a program that uses uninitialized variables. Your program could also print 0 for everything; the variables would still be uninitialized, their values would still be indeterminate, and the program would still be undefined.

Answer (score 4):

You are using uninitialized variables.  What "random garbage" you find in the variables depends on what data was on the stack.  And the data on the stack is more or less random.
You find some variables are zero, because the stack was zero at the place.  And the reason, why the stack was zero, can be random, but also can depend on your program.

Each function call will manipulate the stack and so it COULD happen, that some zeros are "left overs" of some functions that where called before.
And if you think, your program has no functions called before, you better check the machine-code.  There is a lot of things happening, where you don't expect it...

You can read more about the heap and the stack [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/), or just search the internet for it.  And for questions like this, you should really look into machine-code as well ;)